# delegates in ruby explained from a Cocoa developer background

Tags: ruby, cocoa, delegates

I really hope someone can answer this one.  I think I am definitely not the only one confused about this and I wasn't able to find anything that clearly explains this concept.

My understanding of the delegation pattern comes from studying the `Cocoa` framework.  To me, the Cocoa implementation is very clear.  But I am having a very hard time understanding it in Ruby (standard library's `Delegator`, `SimpleDelegator` vs. `ActiveSupport`'s `Delegate`).  It makes little sense to me.  Mostly because one is type safe the other is duck type.  You can see my point already, but allow me to expand... Here is my summary of how to use the delegate pattern in Cocoa:

Our "ingredients" are: 2 classes, `A` and `B` and a `protocol`, which is Cocoa for a pre-defined set of methods to use for delegation.

The implementation of the pattern is basically as follows:

1. `A` defines the set of methods to delegate to `B`.
2. `B`'s delegate is set to be `A`

   => `B` can now call delegated methods like so: `@delegate.send(a_delegated_method)`

What I am not tying together is the fact that Ruby uses duck typing, so you can send any method call to any object, right?  So using the pattern I just explained, as long as the 2 objects are in the same domain you can say while in `A` `@b.send(:a_delegated_method)` and vice versa while in `B` `@a.send(:another_delegated_method)`.

Could it be that the point with delegates in Ruby is where the delegated method is defined?  Meaning that we send from within class `A` to property `@b` (`@b(:delegated_method)`) a `:delegated_method` defined within `A` itself?

Hope this isn't too confusing.  I myself am confused about why delegates even exist in a duck typing language and what the differences are between `Delegator`, `SimpleDelegator` and `ActiveSupport`'s `Delegate`.

Comment: Delegation is a _pattern_. It has nothing to do with how typing works. The two things are not just orthogonal, they are downright unrelated.

Comment: I know it's a pattern, but my question is more about the change of implementing the pattern in 2 different environments if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear to me that you have understood how delegation works in Cocoa. It is true that the common variety of the delegation pattern in Cocoa involves a protocol, but that's just a way of quieting the compiler.

So let's talk first about quieting the compiler. You can't send the `woohoo` message to an object in Objective-C unless one of two things is true:

- The compiler has reason to believe that this object might respond to the `woohoo` message.
- The compiler is made to suspend judgment.

Nowadays, the first approach is usually used - that's what a protocol is for. But this was not always the case. It used to be that delegation depended mostly on *informal protocols*. And there still are informal protocols in Cocoa. The idea is that either the method is injected into NSObject by a category, or else you are careful to type the object as `id` so that it can be sent any message at all.

Now let's talk about dynamism. The reason informal protocols are no longer used is that a feature was introduced allowing protocols to declare optional members. But dynamism is still needed! We may satisfy the *compiler*, one way or another, but at *runtime* we have to make sure that it is safe to send a certain message to a certain object. Your app delegate may adopt UIApplicationDelegate, but Cocoa is not going to send it the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` message unless your app delegate class *implements* `applicationDidBecomeActive:` - if it did, you'd crash, and that wouldn't be very nice.

Moreover, if you can just get past the compiler, you can perform delegation in Objective-C even more dynamically than that, as explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

The idea is that we go right ahead at runtime and send the object the message anyway! If a message arrives that Object A can't handle, it can see if Object B handles it. If it does, it passes the message along to Object B. So we might not crash after all!! I use that approach in one of my apps:

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([self.originalDataSource respondsToSelector: aSelector])
        return self.originalDataSource;
    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
```

In that code, I'm saying that if a message arrives and I can't handle it, I should try to get it sent on to another object, called `self.originalDataSource`.

If you think about it, that is almost identical to Ruby delegation. I have a helper object, and messages that I can't handle are passed on to it.

Another common use of this pattern is when wrapping a Cocoa collection. You can't subclass, say, NSArray, because it's a class cluster, so the proper approach is to wrap it. You then just forward everything to the NSArray, and presto, you are duck-typed as an NSArray! You look like an NSArray as far as your methods are concerned. Then you introduce some difference in behavior, and now you are duck-typed as a customized NSArray.

Comment: When you mention Ruby delegation, are you referring to Rails' ActiveSupport#delegate?  What about the Standard Library's Delegator?  Why even have those if the messages are sent anyway?  Are you saying it is only to handle method_missing exception then?  I realize the 4 questions are overlapping a bit btw :)